# I believe there is a typo in Stroustup's book, third edition page 368. Could someone confirm?

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

I believe there's a typo on this code snippet extracted from Stroustup's book, at its page 368 :

```
template <class X> class std::auto_ptr
{
    template <class Y> struct auto_ptr_ref { /* ... */ }; // helper class
    X * ptr;
    public :
    typedef X element_type;
    explicit auto_ptr(X* p =0) throw() { ptr = 0; }
    auto_ptr (auto_ptr& a) throw() { ptr = a.ptr; a.ptr = 0; } // note: not const auto_ptr&

    /* ... */
};
```

Shouldn't

```
explicit auto_ptr(X* p =0) throw() { ptr = 0; }
```

be

```
explicit auto_ptr(X* p =0) throw() { ptr = p; }
```

instead ?

Comment: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_printing5.html

Comment: There is a type in your question itself it is Stroustrup :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [errata for the book makes some changes](http://www2.research.att.com/%7Ebs/3rd_printing5.html):

> Chapter 14:
>
> pg 367-368 A recent standards change modified the definition of auto_ptr. Please replace the last paragraph on page 367 and page 368 ...

Answer (score -3):

I've looked in that book however I have a newer version, which has some extra pages.

Anyhow, that code looks correct because it's saying p = 0 and by saying ptr = p is the same thing with ptr = 0.

Comment: No. the `p=0` in the argument list is not an assignment, it is a default value.

Comment: No it is not correct by saying ptr = 0 you will never assign the right value in case of constructor with argument call auto_ptr( new MyClass ); you will get 0 and memleak.